# Two similar scripts creating different lists

Tags: python-3.x

I have two python scripts.

Here's the first:

```py
def testListOutput():
    myCount=1
    myList=[[[x for x in range(3)] for y in range(3)] for z in range(3)]
    for i in range(3):
        for j in range(3):
            for k in range(3):
                myList[i][j][k]=myCount
                myCount+=1
    print(myList)
```

It produces the following output in the console: "[[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]], [[10, 11, 12], [13, 14, 15], [16, 17, 18]], [[19, 20, 21], [22, 23, 24], [25, 26, 27]]]"

That's what I was expecting. Here's the second:

```py
def tryDifferentWay():
    myCount=1
    myList=[x for x in range(3)]
    for m in range(2):
        myList=[myList for x in range(3)]
    for i in range(3):
        for j in range(3):
            for k in range(3):
                myList[i][j][k]=myCount
                myCount+=1
    print(myList)
```

Output: [[[25, 26, 27], [25, 26, 27], [25, 26, 27]], [[25, 26, 27], [25, 26, 27], [25, 26, 27]], [[25, 26, 27], [25, 26, 27], [25, 26, 27]]]

Why is the output not the same?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Try avoiding reuse of `myList=[myList for x in range(3)]`. If you are getting stuck with a references to a particular `myList`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, lets look at the two different ways you built up `myList`:

OPTION 1:

```
myList=[[[x for x in range(3)] for y in range(3)] for z in range(3)]
```

OPTION 2:

```
myList=[x for x in range(3)]
for m in range(2):
    myList=[myList for x in range(3)]
```

So, in option 1 everything goes as you expect, a 3x3x3 grid of individual values is initialized to  0, 1 or 2 thanks to your lovely list comprehension.

In option 2, the first line creates a length 3 list and assigns that to `myList` I will call this length 3 list `my3List`.  Then your first pass through the for loop will reassign `myList` to be `[my3List,my3List,my3List]`.

Note that all 3 of those variables point to the same place, the object `my3List` that was created in the first line.  So changing any one of these values will necessairly change the others, because they all point to the same place.  The next pass through the for loop just does this again until you have a 3x3 list of the `my3List` object.

Essentially option 1 makes a 3x3x3 list of individual values, option 2 creates a 3x3 list of references to the exact same length 3 list.

Comment: Thanks, Hoog. Is there a quick way to initialize an n^m size array (list of sublists)? I was using the for loop to see if that would work. But I obviously screwed it up.

Comment: Option 1 with the list comprehension is perfect for initializing lists of lists (or lists of lists of lists....)  just replace some of the `3`s with `m`s and `n`s

Comment: Maybe if I frame what I'm asking it will be easier to understand what I'm getting at. If I wanted to create a class to simplify implementing n^m arrays, is there a way to do it? The list comprehension is easy if your dimensions are predetermined, but I was trying to figure out a way to generalize initializing a multidimensional array. Is there a way to do it?